# How to prevent the comment form from redirecting?

Tags: forms, comments, redirection

I have a page with a View listing comments; the comment form is also in this View. After submitting through the comment form I get redirected to the actual comment, however I would like to stay on the same page that the View is on and not get redirected. I have tried using a number of Ajax modules (Ajax Comments, Asaf etc) with the comment form to prevent the redirect. But for some reason when these modules are installed the comments are no longer saved in the database when submitting the form. I have also tried to use Rules module to trigger a redirect if a comment is saved. However because I need to redirect to the previous URL I'm not quite sure how to input this as a token. Also, since this URL is different depending on which user is logged on I cannot make it absolute. I am using Drupal 7. How could I do this?

Comment: Take a look at the Better comments module which is still a sandbox project. https://www.drupal.org/sandbox/samir_mankar/2342293
This might helps u

Comment: This could be good when it is actually released, but at the moment it looks very similar to Ajax Comments. Is there not an existing way to change the path that the comment module redirects to, or better still a way to change the redirect to a reload instead?